# VBA - Opening a Word Template as a Document - works for some users, but not all

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA, especially when trying to also use Word from Excel and I'm stuck with the following issue. I've got the following code which opens a template as a document, fills in some data and saves the file to the desktop of the user.

```
Function word(Adresse, Nachname)

Dim oApp As word.Application
Dim oDoc As word.Document
Dim TemplateName   As String

    TemplateName = "C:\Users\" & VBA.Environ("UserName") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\templates  \MyLetter.dotm"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Word isn't running so start it
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    oApp.Visible = True
    Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add(TemplateName)
     
    oDoc.Bookmarks("Adresse").Range.InsertAfter Adresse
    oDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\" & VBA.Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Brief " & Nachname & " " & Date & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
 
        
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
```

It works fine for me and my team. However for some other users its not working properly. Instead of opening and saving the document it just opens a document and does nothing else with it when run the first time. Once run again it then does what it's supposed to do.

I just dont get what's the issue or how to get rid of it effectively.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you & have a good day!

Comment: Check if TemplateName returns a valid file for those users where it doesn't work. Maybe if they use Onedrive this doesn't fit for them ...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We all work locally and it must return something valid as it is opening it (just not adding the address or saving it when first run). The path is also correct. The second time its run, with the first document still open, it also does work as expected.

Comment: Try adding a `DoEvents` line immediately after your `Set oDoc = ...` line